# Is it Possible to Design an Entire Operating System or App using ASIC Chips?

Tags: embedded, cpu, asic, performance, operating-system

ASIC chips are hundreds of times faster than traditional chips.

Is it possible to design an entire operating system or application using a full custom ASIC chip?

Based on what I've read I understand ASIC chips are not very flexible so they cannot be re-programmed but what if I do not plan on changing my program in the future and just want to take advantage of the speed increase ASIC offers - is something like this possible or is it limited to relatively simple functionality such as hash functions?

If something like this is possible I have two more questions:

- What magnitude of speed increase can I expect over traditional CPUs?
- What could I expect to spend on such a device (I know it could cost about $1 million to design one such chip)

Thanks

**Edit:**

I think there's a lot of confusion surrounding this question but basically I am trying to understand the limitations of ASIC chips. My understanding is that the only limitation of ASIC chips is that the algorithm (or whatever "software") they run is fixed and cannot be changed (somehow the chips are designed to execute a specific algorithm). So if I had an application which is fixed in nature could the application benefit from ASIC technology?

@JRE "An ASIC is hardware. An operating system is software" - how did I  imply otherwise?

Comment: "Normal CPUs" *are* ASICs. Edit: You removed the name, but not the misunderstanding.

Comment: The reason an ASIC is fast is because it can do only one thing, but do it very well. An ASIC might be extremely fast at doing a certain encoding, but it can't do anything else. A CPU is quite the opposite of that - it can do a lot of things, but because it can, it isn't extremely specialized in any one of them so will perform a bit slower. Trying to put an operating system on an ASIC defeats the entire purpose of using an ASIC.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question, or something like it, before... (sorry, no time to search and verify now)

Comment: @TonyM I am pretty sure the OP have asked something like this before (and apparently it was removed..)

Comment: An ASIC is hardware.  An operating system is software.

Comment: @EugeneSh. lol I just joined the forum now. How could have I asked it before?

Comment: @DavidLynch  I might be wrong, of course or that could be another DavidLynch. But I am pretty sure I saw this name before :)

Comment: @JRE I guess the question is about making some ASIC that will implement Windows in HW :) Possible? Theoretically yes. Practical? Unlikely.

Comment: If you can describe your application using a [Hardware Description Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language), then you can have an ASIC made that implements it.

Comment: So then you have one specialized block to do each task. Like you have one hardware block for each video and audio encoding you may possibly use, each text encoding, each image encoding.... Your machine will be horribly under utilized. Good thing about general purpose computer is, it's general purpose, and it does whatever the program specifies.

Comment: Yes you can put an entire OS on a chip. Yes you could do it on the gate level. Cost will prohibit you from doing so. Intel chips come with a separate processor on board with a linux OS on them. Microprocessors can have an OS on them. The way this question is worded is off topic, visit the help center for tips on writing good questions

Comment: Voting to reopen. I think oldfart's good answer salvages this question.

Comment: There *is no difference* between "ASIC chips" and "traditional chips". They're all chips.

Comment: [Application-specific integrated circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) "...is an integrated circuit (IC) **customized for a particular use, rather than intended for general-purpose use**. For example, a chip designed to run in a digital voice recorder or a high-efficiency Bitcoin miner is an ASIC. Modern ASICs often include entire microprocessors, memory blocks including ROM, RAM, EEPROM, flash memory and other large building blocks. Such an ASIC is often termed a SoC (system-on-chip)."

Comment: because the English language is so much faster than the english language is it possible to write a whole encyclopedia in a single printed book using the English language...yes it is possible but expensive and nobody would bother to try to read it, due to the weight and size (nobody would bother to print it for you either).

Comment: your question makes no sense whatsoever.  what you are trying to ask is can i instead of write a processor in HDL and make a chip that runs software on it, can I write the whole software application as well as the processor in HDL.  Sure, good luck with that, not manufacturable, and nobody would use it even if they could afford it.   Ask something more basic (even though it still is not necessarily appropriate for this site) like I have an equation x = 3x*5y+16;  can I implement that in HDL without using an alu nor converting it to instructions for a cpu...

Comment: to make that a valid question here is my hdl that implements this higher level algorithm, it doesnt sim right for me I get the wrong answer, here is what I tried and here is what I get.   that would be a valid question for this site. and the excercise might trigger the understanding of why we divide the problem in half, a generic processor with software that runs on it...

Comment: the other issue with your question were you perhaps trying to say that an asic implements an hdl design that can run much faster than the same hdl implemented in an fpga?  rather than saying faster than traditional chips instead meaning to say faster than fpgas or cplds?

Answer (score 8):

There are so many wrong statements and assumptions that I don't even know where to start. 
So let's start with my credentials: I have been designing ASICs for 25 years. I have done small, medium and mega chips. (The latter of course as part of a team).

> ASIC chips are hundreds of times faster than traditional chips.

With faster we engineers normally mean the clock speed which is definitely not the case. ASICs run at the same speed as 'normal' chips. After all they are based on the same technology, be it 1.5um or 20 nm (The range with which I have worked).

If we assume hundreds of times faster in functionality. They could be, but only if you can either parallel-up or pipeline the tasks. You would be amazed how often you find that a speed up of five to ten time is the maximum you can achieve.
Some algorithms are ideal like a streaming FFT. Others are nasty and require a lot of effort to speed up (h264) 
(I have heard the new h265 standard is the first time where they starting taking parallel processing into account whilst defining the algorithm.)

> Based on what I've read I understand ASIC chips are not very flexible so they cannot be re-programmed.

With that you imply that chips can be reprogrammed. No, they normally can not be reprogrammed. FPGAs and PLDs can but they are not your standard chips. Chips can run programs which is something totally different. As mentioned in the comments: an ASCI/Chip is hardware, a program is software.

Then we get to the core of your question which I would summarise as
*How much speed up can I expect if a convert my program into hardware*

Nobody can tell.
As I said: it depends on how much of the algorithm can be made to run in parallel or can be pipelined. If you need one end result N and to produce that you need result N-1 you have a problem. If you need a stream of results then ultimately you can instance X cores each working on a result and start them one after the other.

As to cost: I would say a small one is between 500K and 1M. If you need analogue IP (PLL, MIPPI, HDMI, USB, PCIe, SMPS, etc.) your price quickly goes up to 1.5M. Add to that the cost of the ASIC design team.

Comment: I like the answer. Nice. I think the OP could use a few additional thoughts, so I may write a supplementary answer (if perhaps one that is from a less well-informed background, as mine is instead as an Intel employee working as a chipset and CPU tester using FPGAs -- plus from my interactions for monster sized x86 simulation boxes built out of FPGAs that Intel used prior to FABing an instance of RTL.)

Comment: Thanks for your response (instead of down voting a perfectly legitimate question) @jonk I would be very interested in your response too :) Thanks!

Comment: @DavidLynch Unfortunately, the question has been locked and I'm unable to provide what I'd written for you. Life, I guess.

Comment: A friend from ASIC industry told me that some part of ASIC can be reconfigured these days. Not sure if its true.